# How to create a gradient over an img tag

Tags: html, image, gradient, css

I am creating a website witha a background image that needs to resize with the browser window to match its height. I've used the following code to achieve this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#background-image {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
background-image: url('image.jpg');
z-index: -1;
}
</style>
<img id="background-image" src="image.jpg" />
```

Now what I want to do is apply a gradient over this image--so that it fades to white on the left--that matches the image's adjusting dimensions. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the code generated on this site: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

I think u can also use a `z-index` and png file.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is matching the size of either the div with the gradient styling or a png gradient with the img.

Comment: So CSS method should work. Just create the class, use a img tag, and draw it over existing image. In that case you don't need a size of a image or div.

Comment: Unfortunatley this background gradient cannot simply be applied over an img tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS to combine both the background image and the gradient

```
url('image.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat 100% 100%, linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #ffffff 100%);
```

with the values that work best for you.